# Burgermenu: providing round border around it

Tags: html, css

I have the following hamburger menu:

```css
.bar {
  width: 25px;
  height: 3px;
  background-color: #ace1f5;
  margin: 4px 0;
}

.BurgerIcon {
  margin-right: 31px;
}
```

```html
<div class="burgericon">
  <div class="bar"></div>
  <div class="bar"></div>
  <div class="bar"></div>
</div>
```

And I want to achieve the following:

[image: rounded border]
(forgive me for paint skills).

How can I achieve this rounded border?

I have tried the `border-radius` property and some other stuff but no success yet.

Comment: pay attention to typo error .. css is case sensitive

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are on the right track with `border-radius`. Make sure your class definition matches your class assignment (`.BurgerIcon` is not the same as `.burgericon`).

To get the circle, give a `border-radius: 50%;` then also add the `border` as well as `padding` and `width`.

The following code works so long as `box-sizing` is not set to `border-box`.

```css
.bar {
  width: 25px;
  height: 3px;
  background-color: #ace1f5;
  margin: 4px 0;
}

.burgericon {
  margin-right: 31px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 1px solid #ace1f5;
  padding: 5px;
  width: 25px;
}
```

```html
<div class="burgericon">
  <div class="bar"></div>
  <div class="bar"></div>
  <div class="bar"></div>
</div>
```

With `box-sizing:border-box;`

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.bar {
  width: 25px;
  height: 3px;
  background-color: #ace1f5;
  margin: 4px 0;
}

.burgericon {
  margin-right: 31px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 1px solid #ace1f5;
  padding: 5px;
  width: 37px; /* width of bar (25px) + width of padding (10px) + width of both sides border (2px) */
}
```

```html
<div class="burgericon">
  <div class="bar"></div>
  <div class="bar"></div>
  <div class="bar"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

Make the parent element inline-block, then add some padding and border:

```css
.bar {
  width: 25px;
  height: 3px;
  background-color: #ace1f5;
  margin: 4px 0;
}

.burgericon {
  margin: 30px;
  display:inline-block;
  padding:10px;
  border:2px solid blue;
  border-radius:50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="burgericon">
  <div class="bar"></div>
  <div class="bar"></div>
  <div class="bar"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this:

```
.burgericon {
    border: 1px solid #ace1f5;
    height: 25px;
    width: 25px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    padding: 10px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your CSS class has a typo in the css file.

Here is an example with just playing around with some css values using the border-radius properties and messing with the margins, you could probably make it prettier with some adjustments

```css
.bar {
  width: 25px;
  height: 3px;
  background-color: #ace1f5;
  margin-top:5px;
  margin-left:5px;
}

.burgericon {
    border: 2px solid blue;
    height: 35px;
    border-radius:50%;
    width: 35px;
}
```

```html
<div class="burgericon">
  <div class="bar"></div>
  <div class="bar"></div>
  <div class="bar"></div>
</div>
```